# spring rest example from git not working

Tags: java

yesterday i tried the "spring rest-example"
and im pretty sure it worked, but on a different pc it did not...just gives me a customized 404 from jetty.

so in the evening i tried it again on the first pc and for whatever reason maven updated a bunch of libraries when executing site:run and i got the same error message.

the pcs are different, but i believe its a library problem....how do you troubleshoot something like this?

since the code is pulling in jetty 6.1.25 which looks quite old according to the version information i tried to use a current one for it, this is my modified pom.xml

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
            <configuration>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>9999</port>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but it is ignored. i found these lines of code here [1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.4.6.v20170531) but now on a second look im not really sure if i need jetty-maven-plugin or jetty-server is the right software to use here...the maven descriptions are rather short.
Any ideas?

In [2](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html) it says that if you execute the goal jetty:run the jetty server will start and constantly check if your code is uptodate and refresh it if needed.
sadly jetty:run throws this:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider   org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
```

which seems to be some problem between tomcat-jdbc and jetty on a quick google search. also tomcat-jdbc is not mentioned when running dependency:tree [3]

so how do i get my project to use a current jetty to try if the error disappears or what would you do to solve this?

please remove the spaces in the link to open, thank you.
[3] https :// bpaste.net /show/ 3f943e33827a

Comment: Please do not use links to external resources. They will change/disappear, making your question useless for future readers. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: im explaing what i found where, im just referencing it if somebody is interrested or wants to check. if the links disappear the post still makes sense. the bpaste link is set to "forever".

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what changed, but another checkout and it was working.
I did run a git pull on the old sources and it said my local checkout was uptodate.